# Как сделать так, чтобы окно скрипта не закрывалось?

Tags: c#

Проблема такая, вызываю скрипт (__FileName) из своего приложения, вот код:

```
    private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ruby.exe",
            Arguments = __FileName,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        var p = Process.Start(psi);

        textBox2.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

окно скрипта появляется и сразу же исчезает, даже если в скрипте прописать "gets". Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я вам писал в [предыдущем ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472295/106), что надо добавить `p.WaitForExit()`;

Comment: Да, спасибо, но все равно, к сожалению, не помогает.

Comment: Откройте консоль и попробуйте запустить это приложение с теми же параметрами. Что-нибудь выведет?

Comment: Приложение работает правильно если запустить его через консоль или даже кликнув по нему два раза левой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: А попробуйте запустить от имени администратора: `psi.Verb = "runas";`

Comment: Вставил эту строку перед вызовом процесса - никакого эффекта. Вообще, если отлаживать мое приложение по шагам, то когда стрелка переходит со строки `var p = Process.Start(psi);` на следующую строку, видно как появляется и сразу же закрывается окно консоли.

Comment: Выяснил, что если убрать следующие строки: `RedirectStandardOutput = true;`,`RedirectStandardError = true;`,`UseShellExecute = false;`,`textBox2.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` и вставить после `var p = Process.Start(psi);` `p.WaitForExit();` то окно действительно не исчезает, но и записи в текстбокс не происходит.

Comment: А в окне что-то пишется при этом?

Comment: Да, пишется все как надо. В принципе, меня уже все устраивает. Т.е. могу обойтись и без вывода в текстбокс, консоли достаточно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вся проблема в том, что ты запускаешь консольное приложение и по закрытии оно автоматически закрывает консоль.

То есть я вижу 2 варианта:

1. А если ты откроешь именно консоль и в ней уже будешь запускать сам скрипт -- окно не закроется. Потому как по окончанию работы програмы она просто вернется в отрытую консоль, а не закроет окно
2. В самом скрипте запилить какойнить ReadKey в конце самого скрипта. Результат будет приблизительно тот же.